# Install gradle on Centos

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I'm trying to install gradle for building android app with the help of Jenkins. But I'm not able to find the link to download gradle for Centos. I tried to use binaries from `https://gradle.org/downloads/`, but when I unzipped I got gradle.bat file inside bin directory which tells me that this is for Windows.

Is there a place where I can download gradle for using in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...  but when I unzipped I got `gradle.bat` file inside bin directory which tells me that this is for Windows.

It also contains a file called `gradle`, which is a shell script.

Your download is also suitable for running on any Linux or UNIX platform .... including CentOS.

Comment: When I'm running gradle command, I;m getting message, `command not found`

Comment: Do you have the bin directory on your search path?

Comment: Do you have `java` on the search path and/or have you set `$JAVA_HOME` correctly?   Does the `gradle` file have the owner-execute bit set?

Comment: Yes. Even when my pwd is gradle/bin,.. gradle command is not working

Comment: Add `set -x` as the 2nd line of the file.  That will tell you what command it cannot find.  That file is definitely a (well written) shell script, and the fact that it isn't working suggests to me that you have made a mistake in the way you have installed and configured ,,, either Gradle itself or Java.

Comment: *"Even when my pwd is gradle/bin"* -  That doesn't necessarily help ... unless you run it as `./gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the `GRADLE_HOME` path to the `PATH` variable by using following steps:

1. `echo $PATH`
2. Copy the echoed paths and add the `GRADLE_HOME` path e.g.: `/opt/gradle/bin` to the PATH variable using a colon (`:`) using command: `export PATH =` echoed paths`:GRADLE_HOME path`
3. Now, you can use the command `gradle` from any path and it should work.